# Observable result won't map to variable

Tags: .net, angular

[image: Console Snapshot of Observable Data]

In the code above i have the result of an observable that is not mapping to the variable i defined for it.  I added a separate call just to make sure it was returning data and logged the result to the console.

This is my service call

```
`GetNeedsApprovalList(): Observable<needApprovalItems[]>
{
const url = this.configService.buildUrl('ApprovalRequest/GetItemsForApproval');
return this.http.get<needApprovalItems[]>(url);
}`
```

Comment: It is possible, it is asynchronous call.  you can check it in the subscribe method

Comment: all the documentation says to do it in this fashion.  did i implement it incorrectly?

Comment: which document says this? I believe you need to use it in the subscribe method.

Comment: [link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#call-it-in-ngoninit)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the document. you can check the final code. It uses the value in the subscribe method not after the service call. And Angular use Observable to deal with HTTP,  Observable is lazy, you need to get the real data in the 'subscribe' method.

Comment: It's possible.  For some reason, it's working today.  So i'm going to close the ticket and study some more.

Answer (score 0):

It is mapping to your variable, just not when you think it is.

The HTTP call happens asynchronously, so the rest of your ngOnInit method runs while it waits on the HTTP response.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to update automatically when the call completes?  and why does the second call show data in the console?

Comment: What updates automatically will be your HTML template (if you’re displaying approvalItems there). Angular‘s change detection should automatically pick that up. For your console, once it’s logged out, there’s nothing that can go back and update that. Your second log is actually in the subscription, so it’s waiting until the service completes. This is different from your other logs that are executed synchronously.

Comment: The data goes into the approvalItem array and that array is used as the datasource for a table in the template.  But the data never makes it into the approvalItem array